# Create Folder that can not accessible by any other application

Tags: android, directory

i want to create a one folder that can not accessible by any other application.

Is it possible to do this ? If yes then give me the solution how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use internal storage like so:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to use the storage that is private to your app.

Comment: if i copy 1 gb files in that internal storage folder then whats the effect ?

Comment: Your overall available memory reduces.

Comment: is it affect on application performace ?

Answer (score 1):

On the SD card (without a rooted phone) you can't create a folder which is only accessible by your application.

But everything you write to your "internal storage" is only accessible by your application.
see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: if i copy 1 gb files in that internal storage folder then whats the effect ?